# After rebooting amazon ec2 instance, can't access instance with domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have first reboot the instance. After that when I tried to access instance with domain name, it's not accessible.

I can access with elastic ipaddress (whm and cpanel both i can access with ip address) but with domain name, i am not able to access.

Help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later on found that I have created instance with cpanel with public ip address instead of using elastic ip address...

Basically it issue regarding ip address only.

After that I have created new instance with cpanel Linux and installed cpanel with elastic ip address, in that case after rebooting this issue didn't happen again.  Btw it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the domain to check if it returns the actual IP address of the server?

```
ping domain.com
```

Let me know if it returns the correct IP, otherwise there must be something wrong with the DNS. Or most probably your DNS server is down or misconfigured entries. If you're using Cloudflare or any other 3rd party DNS provider, then you need to turn of proxy bypass for the domain in order to access the server directly through domain name.

Comment: It returns the correct ip address.

Comment: Later on found that I have increased instance with cpanel with public ip address instead of using elastic ip address... Basically it issue regarding ip address only.  After that I have created new instance with cpanel Linux and installed cpanel with elastic ip address, in that case after rebooting this issue didn't happen again.  Btw it solved.